# Create a Picture Content Control in the OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to create content controls using the OpenXML SDK so that a different program can then pick up the document and edit it as required.

I manage to create Text Content Controls successfully but picture content controls have proven to be more challenging.

The closest I got was with the following code:

```
var sdtCBlock = new SdtContentBlock(new Paragraph(new Run()));

var sdtPr = new SdtProperties(
                new SdtAlias {Val = "" },
                new Tag {Val = ""},
                new SdtContentPicture(),
                new DataBinding {XPath = ""}
            );

wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new SdtCell(sdtPr, sdtCBlock));
```

This creates an empty content control that word recognises as a picture:

**Empty picture content control**

[image: Empty picture content control]

The problem is that the second program will not insert the picture into this content control as is. However, if we open the word file manually and click on the content control to pop up the blue square template then the second program successfully detects and changes the image in the content control.

**Content control with blue square template after being manually clicked on**

[image: Content control with blue square template after being manually clicked on]

Am I doing something wrong? And how can I use the OpenXml code to generate the placeholder with the template in order to be picked up by the second program?

Comment: Try comparing using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. For the first, take the result document without the picture content control (comment out that part of your code). For the second, open a copy of the first document and manually insert a picture content control. You should get the code the Tool generates to change the first document into the second.

Comment: @CindyMeister -  I tried that but there are a lot of changes and some that I am not able to correctly map to Open XML commands. The biggest change is the creation of the template through the drawing object [link] (https://imgur.com/a/buT7TmA)